# failed to connect to daemon on tails

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, daemon

My cli wallet was working before but now I get the error mesage when I log in (or refresh) that the wallet cannot connect to daemon.

> Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: >2xmrnode5itf65lz.onion:18081. Daemon either is not started or wrong >port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the >daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.

There is still coins in my wallet but I can't use them because of this issue.

Did some research and this triggered me to run `monerod`

This is still running now, but it did already give some warning messages, like

> no two valid DNS TXT records were received

and

> No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080

I do not know anything of how crypto works behind the hood, and I am really worried that I will have lost my coin. I do still have my seed for this wallet.

Does anyone know whatwould be the best way to troubleshoot this issue, or get going again with this wallet?

Also, I am confused about what `monerod` does. I read that it might be downloading lots of data. However, I am running my wallet on a usb stick in Tails and if that's the case there will most likely not be enough space on it to complete this command.

Thank you so much for trying to helping me out! Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By changing the log-level, I just found out that ```monerod``` is constantly returning error code saying that it 'failed to connect to xxx.xx.xxx.xx:18080. This is interspersed with the message "Failed to connect to any of seed peers, continuing without seeds"

Comment: Check that `ping xxx.xx.xxx.xx` returns responses. If you have it, try `nmap xxx.xx.xxx.xx`. And check that `/etc/resolv.conf` contains valid dns servers.

Comment: https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor-on-tails

Comment: Got the same problem, not connected the daemon apparently... still working on it